# Make tab indent the current line

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to write Java and finding the default <kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour (inserting a tab at the cursor position) quite annoying. I want it to behave like <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> de-indents the cursor line if there is no selection, or every line in the selection if there is one, regardless of the cursor's position on the line. I tried to make <kbd>Tab</kbd> behave the same way by changing the keymap settings: I unbound the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key from **Editor Actions** → **Tab** so that it'd perform **Edit** → **Indent Selection**. But that only makes it indent the selection: if there's no selection, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> now does nothing.

It appears that the de-indent action for <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> is actually **Editor Actions** → **Unindent Selection**, but there's no corresponding action for indenting.

How can I make the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key indent the current line (increase the indent by one stop) if there is no selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which selects the nearest item to the cursor and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to unindent the current line.

Answer (score 7):

1. Remove the keyboard shortcut from "Tab"
2. Add "Tab" as a keyboard shortcut to "Indent Line or Selection".  When the dialog pops up asking you to "Leave" or "remove", click "Leave".

This works on at least IDEA 14+ but I haven't tested it on anything before that

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you need, but you can try `Code` | `Auto-Indent Lines`. There is also a [known bug about the difference in the selection indent/unindent behavior](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-53093).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see the bug was first reported three years ago, so I won't hold my breath for an official fix.